# Adding an Intellij IDEA Live Template for Iterating over a java.util.Map

Tags: java, dictionary, intellij-idea, live-templates

I'm currently adding a Live Template for iterating over a java.util.Map in my IDEA, as we can do with 'itmap' template under Netbeans.

The goal is to generate this kind of scriptlet :

```
    for (Entry<KeyObject, ValueObject> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        KeyObject key = entry.getKey();
        ValueObject value = entry.getValue();
        |
    }
```

Here my current work in progress :
[image: iterate over a Map template]

Raw template code :

```
$ELEMENT_TYPE$ $VAR$ = $ENTRY$.entrySet();
for($ITER_TYPE$ $ITER$ : $VAR$) {
    $KEY_TYPE$ $KEY_VAR$ = $ITER$.getKey();
    $VALUE_TYPE$ $VALUE_VAR$ = $ITER$.getValue();
    $END$
}
```

Currently, when I invoke the template, I obtain the following Java code :

```
    Set<Entry<KeyObject, ValueObject>> entrySet = myMap.entrySet();
    for (Entry<KeyObject, ValueObject> entry : entrySet) {
        KeyObject key = entry.getKey();
        ValueObject value = entry.getValue();
        |
    }
```

This code is pretty buy I want to inline the first line into 'entry' variable.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Could you clarify what "I want to inline the first line into 'entry' variable" menas? Perhaps you could post an example of what you are expecting.

Comment: I just edited my question with an example. Thank you

Comment: Can you not simply replace the first two lines of your template with `for($ITER_TYPE$ $ITER$ : $ENTRY$.entrySet()) {`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Trisha, it is the heart of my problem : I try it, but $ITER_TYPE$ uses the unction "iterableComponentType(VAR)". And if I replace "VAR" by something like "ENTRY.entrySet()", it doesn't work... So I genereate the first line to have this variable.

Comment: Ah yes, I see.  To be honest, I couldn't get the iterableComponentType to work at all in my version for some reason. I think you won't be able to get the live template to automatically inline the variable, that's something you'd have to do manually.

Comment: The only other observation I have is that if you're following this pattern of iterating over Maps frequently, you might want to consider alternative data structures - although obviously you can iterate over Maps, this is not the main strength of this data structure.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 10 and later, this has become easier, since we can use local variable type inference. A template like this should work:

```
for(var $ITER$ : $ENTRY$.entrySet()) {
    $KEY_TYPE$ $KEY_VAR$ = $ITER$.getKey();
    $VALUE_TYPE$ $VALUE_VAR$ = $ITER$.getValue();
    $END$
}
```

with all the (remaining) template variables set as in the original question.